# Stack Overflow hacked? Got redirected to stackoverflow.com.80bola.com on login

Tags: support

Saw something *really* weird while trying to login. Not sure if it was a MITM attack or if it was a legit domain, or if Stack Overflow was compromised.

While clicking on the "Ask Question" button, my browser was immediately redirected to **80bola.com**. When I checked the primary domain, it wasn't any kind of CDN, it looked like some sketchy sports website.

The URL specifically was http://stackoverflow.com.80bola.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f29570032%2fbad-react-js-performance-with-associated-data-and-two-way-binding.

I'm a little skeptical that it's local malware, though it could be a bad plugin. My other guess is someone is hosting a proxy site of Stack Overflow. I'm using Mac OSX on latest Chrome.

Ideas?

### Edit

I did a quick Google search and it would indeed appear that this is not local malware, but someone is blatantly proxying Stack Overflow for the search rankings and ad revenue (my guess). Here's a screenshot of Google:

[image: Google Search 80bola.com]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250916/what-is-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com

Comment: Seems like this might be malware on your computer, there are plenty of people asking about this site popping up for no reason. If SO was hacked, they wouldn't need to redirect you to a proxy, they'd just grab what they want.

Comment: The real question is how did you land on this site. Can you check your history to see the exact path you took?

Comment: Hey guys related link from @tux3 is correct. It looks like some sort of proxy. I've updated my question. I bet I wasn't on the original domain, but landed there via Google.

Comment: @crockpotveggies Could you check your history just to be sure? It's bugging me :)

Comment: @tux3 I can confirm the 80bola.com domain was indeed in my history. Totally caught me off-guard. I'd bet those guys are link farming and boosting up their search results.

Comment: Yeah. I wonder if there's some place this can be reported. To Google maybe.

Answer (score 6):

As @tux3 pointed out with this related link: [What is stackoverflow.com.80bola.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250916/what-is-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com), *80bola.com* is some sort of proxy website for StackOverflow. No idea what the goal of the website is, but it is probably not a good idea to use it for various reasons.

I was caught off-guard since I didn't notice that the Google search result I clicked was actually hosted on the 80bola.com domain.

Comment: I would NEVER log into that site.