# Stack Overflow fraud page

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

Was looking for a standard question and stumbled over the following fraud of Stack Overflow:

[image: 80bola.com]

The shown link in the image is not a duplicate of Stack Overflow showing the same content, it is using Stack Overflow search combinations to link to their own products.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because this topic has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Comment: Thx wrote a report email

Comment: If they're attributing the original content (given stackoverflow.com is in the url, I'm guessing they are?), then what they're doing is fine, as per the post linked to.

Comment: Nope tey dont, after clicking the link you are landing straight on http://www.aliexpress.com/item/ZTE-Blade-S6-5-inch-HD-IPS-1280-720-Android-5-0-Qualcomm-Octa-Core-1/32280732091.html?aff_platform=aaf&sk=jAI6YJeAQ%3A&cpt=1430215729267&aff_trace_key=36747231521196590

Comment: Ah, in that case then - report away!

Comment: @jungerislaender , can you give a link to that google search ( or what ever search engine you were using )

Comment: Or either of these: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289072/is-this-another-stack-overflow-clone-wrapper-fake http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290490/stackoverflow-hacked-got-redirected-to-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com-on-login (All three are specifically about this proxy)

Comment: SOrry i cant recreate the google search. I just can provide you the following Link:
https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CD8QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com.80bola.com%2Fquestions%2F26383747%2Fadd-field-for-custom-class-in-typo3-ce&ei=LFg_VZO2J8T1OO7WgdAK&usg=AFQjCNFxmCIA8eLQG06DyTVPpZ8ueJ9gtw&cad=rja

Answer (score 0):

As answered by James Thorpe in comments you can read then regulations about Fraud Pages here:

[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

and if its violating the rules write to the support:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact