# 4 Fakes Stack Overflow Sites

Tags: support, copycat-sites

***Info :***

Searching about a question, I found those phishing sites targeting Stack Overflow.
Google returned me this result.

<sub>***Warning !*** Don't open that link directly; be prudent use another secure browser, This site will request you to install a software on your machine and opens a bunch of popups. Visit at your own peril, or better yet, don't.</sub>

***Sites :***

www.ftssales.net

www.samhohce.net

stackoverflow.com.80bola.com

stackoverflow.wwwblogher.com (new one)

careersstackoverflow.wwwblogher.com (new one)

***Notes :***

[List of some sites owned by ftssales scammer](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:whois.domaintools.com%20%22YOU%20CHANGKUN%22)

Other, similar question: [Is this (another) Stack Overflow clone/wrapper/fake?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289072/is-this-another-stack-overflow-clone-wrapper-fake)

Comment: Report it on https://www.phishtank.com/

Comment: For the more general case of a clone site, see [What to do about a clone service scraping SO sites for content?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: This is a bit more malicious than a mere clone. It's filled with malware, popups, all that typical stuff.

Comment: @Cerbrus: hmm, didn't go to the site, interesting.

Comment: You are just seeing the side-effect of SO gathering a lot of link traps and poor content that can't be effectively moderated anymore.  These vampire sites have a much easier time lately getting ahead in the Google ranking by filtering the junk.  Some background [is here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280328/did-google-recently-update-algorithms-in-a-way-thats-bad-for-stack-overflow-que).

Comment: See also: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/262755)

Comment: @Hans i don't think google is well ranking this site i did an advanced search with " " looking for a duplicate question on stackoverflow also, there was just 2 pages of results, i did not check all the links, others copy may possibly exist

Comment: so mods pay attention to your link-bar if you are searching for duplicate with google

Comment: The link now redirects me to http://stackexchange.com/about/malware

Comment: www.ftssales.net is still there it's a whole copy

Comment: anyone else think this part is hilarious? "Protected & Accelerated by Incapsula 10,961,454 threats blocked this month" at the bottom. [scamadvisor says incapsula is trusted](http://www.scamadviser.com/is-Incapsula.com-a-fake-site.html) take that with however many grains of salt you please. If incapsula is legit, should we report the phishing site to them?

Comment: @humble.rumble and can you imagine the amount of junk **without** their protection? Boy am I glad they were there to protect me from the nazi virus menace on the internets (yes, with an "s").

Comment: I reported this site two weeks ago as well. For future reference: just contact SE through the "[Contact Us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)" link at the bottom. They'll start the lengthy process that takes care of it.

Comment: @humble.rumble: Since scamadviser is flagged by MyWOT as being [a scam site itself](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/scamadviser.com), this is anything but surprising.

Comment: @intika "Warning! This site will request to install software on your machine and opens a bunch of popups. Visit at your own peril, or better yet, don't." I guess using linux and adblock exempts you from this.

Comment: And the signup and signin links redirect to http://www.samhohce.net/ which is another clone.

Comment: @humble.rumble yes (just plugins disabled and cookies cleaned is enough) but it's better to advice curious

Comment: @humble.rumble: I added that warning in there because many users don't have plugins like adblock.

Comment: @Cerbrus sorry that was a joke

Comment: Here we go with an other one stackoverflow.wwwblogher.com

Comment: _"stackoverflow.com.80bola.com (new one)"_ [This one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287439/site-duplicating-stack-overflow-potential-privacy-security-issue) [isn't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289072/is-this-another-stack-overflow-clone-wrapper-fake) [new.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290490/stackoverflow-hacked-got-redirected-to-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com-on-login) It's been reported before, since April even.

Comment: I appreciate the diligence but I don't see the need to re-open this question(? discussion?). You can report scrapers to SO, no further need to discuss anything. For the record: I asked, and was told, the same thing, and since then I *report* them directly, without discussing on Meta.